# How do I have an animation play on app launch and how do I use SwiftyGif on GitHub?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, animation, gif

I'm extremely new to Swift and App development, and have scoured every source I could find, but there's not a definitive step by step process that describes how to do this.

The closest to a solution I have encountered was on this [website](https://www.amerhukic.com/animating-launch-screen-using-gif). However, it's a rather vague tutorial for a beginner. I've run into these problems and am unsure of what to do at this point, would appreciate it if someone could help me out, thanks in advance!

1. I'm not sure what to do with the SwiftyGif file after cloning it from GitHub
2. Towards the bottom of the Website Link above it states that "SwiftyGif allows us to load GIFs using a UIImageView and also to control when to start and end the GIF animation." How do I import the SwiftyGif file into the current file I am working on so that I may load the Gif to get a UI view?
3. Which documents would I put the lines of code towards the bottom of that page?

Comment: You can simply use lottie and animate in Launch Screen. 
 * This is lottie animation files: https://lottiefiles.com
 * Github: https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-ios